# Why does my JWT Token' from Amazon Cognito have an invalid signature?

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito

I am working on Amazon cognito. I am trying to decode from https://jwt.io

> eyJraWQiOiJRaGF4STZGbXB5Y3Z3dUV5TUZJUk9FTm5MTDJKTiswMzVVak5MNTEycjZvPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJhYjI0YzExYS1mNjZhLTRjMjktOWVhNy0yMWQwMTc2NmZlN2IiLCJhdWQiOiIxY2ZxNjJubjNlZmNpdWFpYnFldmlxbHU4OSIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImlkIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNDk0Njg1MjQwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvY29nbml0by1pZHAudXMtZWFzdC0xLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb21cL3VzLWVhc3QtMV9oM3F4WGVPQzQiLCJjb2duaXRvOnVzZXJuYW1lIjoidGVzdHNhbmRlZXAxIiwiZXhwIjoxNDk0Njg4ODQwLCJpYXQiOjE0OTQ2ODUyNDAsImVtYWlsIjoic2FuZGVlcC5qYWtrYXJhanVAZm9jYWxjeG0uY29tIn0.ZRsYZZwxUnqL4FfuWhD-w8xQWoQQkuj4rYCYPqQehcq1SMe0Vww2GIY4-sr9RgwjVxhOo4WqIQT8LzSn_tFBF504h5xGpp5fD37rIJZ49rC3naH7tC0nHwKSswi6C6x8BlIPi4QAnlP49SZMoIEPEnQig9F6wzlDfb-cjw0R2q61Em-e0cpBM8lbjxCrgBF2-PbXFqwEfncEUkwb93qZHo4Wk3pYH3d-9aXzZg6Xc4CNZfehAUZ7qknq2qtaSI3tH-EXGYmytjoVwcF5jIvej2OATrQf_JbfBNSxC96oA_CglWVKvp2rPrqlZzDCd0Se68TjZvKSbW7XtKX_DzI5ww

It says the signature invalid. I have tried many tokens I am always getting this.

Why does it report that the signature is invalid?

Comment: look in the lower right on the jwt.io page: 'Verify Signature' 'Public Key or Certificate: Enter it...' Without the Public Key, Certificate or Secret you can't verify the token.

Answer (score 7):

@jps is correct. You need to download the JWKs for your Cognito User Pool before you can verify the signature of the JWT.

1. Download your Cognito User Pools JWK file: `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json`. This for your User Pool is: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_h3qxXeOC4/.well-known/jwks.json
2. Find your Identities `kid` value. The value from the token you provided is: `"QhaxI6FmpycvwuEyMFIROENnLL2JN+035UjNL512r6o="`.
3. You then need to generate the Public Key that matches the data provided from the JWKs file, that matches your `kid` key. This is blogged about here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/ (look further down the blog post for how to generate the Public Key).

Comment: Thanks David and @jps.

Comment: What happens if in step 2 your kid does not match the jwks file from cognito?  I'm using Cognito user pool - that uses Azure to login and then the load balancer is controlling authentication through Cognito.  The data access token is JWT token but it has an invalid signature. Can someone help me figure out out how to fix the signature being invalid

Comment: @user1633146 Did you figure out ?